# Single key input property in UI Panel

Tags: python, scripting

How to capture a single key user input in the UI panel of the add-on?

[The UILayout documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html) mentions an `event` parameter in the `prop` method. If this is set to `True`, there appears a single key input control in the UI Panel. But I am unable to capture the key pressed on this control.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To capture a single key, the `event` param of prop in UILayout needs to be set to `True` and the corresponding property needs to be an EnumProperty with **ALL** the key codes mapped.

When the user presses a key on the control, the EnumProperty item that is related to the code of the key pressed, gets selected.

Please post your answer if you have any better alternative.